# Duplicate Declaration of Method 'ApplicationDidBecomeActive'

Tags: objective-c, error-handling

```
//  Created by Robert Van Gilder on 30/05/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Robert Van Gilder. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];

    {[Parse setApplicationId:@"ycWShHVTsY7Xawt0dupTN1YMWFeyMLlhG7K9R0rZ"
                   clientKey:@"8AmzExUoqvmppa5k3eaS37RBNB6c1StmlysvvjBr"];}

    {[PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];}

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

    UIViewController* initialViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController"];

    self.window.rootViewController  = initialViewController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;


}



    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
openURL:(NSURL *)url
sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                        withSession:[PFFacebookUtils session]];
}

    - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
        [FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActiveWithSession:[PFFacebookUtils session]];
    }


- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

I get the error in the title at 
`- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application.` I don't get why this happens. I'm using the Parse SDK along with the Facebook login, and I'm following Parse's instructions, however when I add this code part below, the compiler doesn't understand it properly and creates various errors.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                        withSession:[PFFacebookUtils session]];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActiveWithSession:[PFFacebookUtils session]];
}
```

Comment: Zev is correct, remove the applicaitonDidBecomeActive method that is not indented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a duplicate declaration of `-applicationDidBecomeActive`. The first one is indented incorrectly, just below `-application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`. The second is between `-applicationWillEnterForeground:` and `-applicationWillTerminate:`.

Comment: No, it isn't doubled. The entire delegate is on top

Comment: Ah. Stupid Stack Overflow + OS X scroll bars meant I could only see part of your code, and didn’t realize there was more.

Comment: Updated my answer. You definitely have a duplicate. Use the Find command if you’re having trouble finding it.

Comment: Thank you, I just deleted the second duplicate and the application ran just fine! However,I get a breakpoint at  [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];    and the app crashes. Do you have any idea why that happens?

Comment: @RobertVanGilder please post a new question with details of the crash.

Comment: I posted a new question :)

Comment: @RobertVanGilder can you post the link to your new question please?